# Using gitlab-runner will result in an "error: bogus format in GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS" error

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Using gitlab-runner will result in an "error: bogus format in GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS" error.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.3.3 (febb2a09)
  on MACHINE 4nC48mnS
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on MACHINE...
Getting source from Git repository 00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/4nC48mnS/0/dev/test/.git/
error: bogus format in GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
fatal: unable to parse command-line config
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Gitlab-runner's abstract.go has a git fetch -c option.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/main/shells/abstract.go

```
    userAgent := fmt.Sprintf("http.userAgent=%s %s %s/%s", v.Name, v.Version, v.OS, v.Architecture)

    fetchArgs := []string{"-c", userAgent, "fetch", "origin"}
    fetchArgs = append(fetchArgs, build.GitInfo.Refspecs...)
    if depth > 0 {
        fetchArgs = append(fetchArgs, "--depth", strconv.Itoa(depth))
    }

    fetchArgs = append(fetchArgs, build.GetGitFetchFlags()...)

    w.Command("git", fetchArgs...)
```

However, git's fetch command does not have -c.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/fetch-options.txt

Even if the command is actually executed, an error occurs.

```
# git -c http.userAgent=gitlab-runner fetch origin
error: bogus format in GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
fatal: unable to parse command-line config
```

How do you operate it?

- gitlab : 14.3.3
- gitlab-runner : 14.3.3
- git : 2.35.2
- target OS : RHEL8.4

(6/23 Added)

```
# echo $GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS

# test -v GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
# echo $?
1
# cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[user]
        name = aaaaaa@example.com
        password = "aaaaaa"
[remote "origin"]
        url = http://githostname/dev/test.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Succeeds if -c option is not used.

```
# git fetch origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 15, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 6
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), 1.22 KiB | 52.00 KiB/s, done.
From http://githostname/dev/test
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
# git -c http.userAgent=gitlab-runner  fetch origin
error: bogus format in GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS
fatal: unable to parse command-line config
```

So I think the -c option is bad.
Do you use the -c option? What to do ... Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: if *you're* not setting it, and `git fetch` works but `git -c a=b fails` for any `a` and `b`, that would indicate that the installed Git is somehow mis-configured: the front end `git` command and the operational commands such as `fetch` are not talking to each other correctly.  In that case, Git probably needs to be reinstalled.

(Original answer below)

---

`GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` is an environment variable.

Never use it.  Do not set it.  If you avoid it, you won't run into its glitches (there are several).  Something is setting it: find out what and why, and fix that.

> Gitlab-runner's abstract.go has a git fetch -c option.

Not quite: it has a `git -c` option.

> ```
> # git -c http.userAgent=gitlab-runner fetch origin
> ```

Note how the `-c` option is passed to `git`, not to `fetch`.

(Nothing in GitLab should be setting `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS`, since that particular item is meant for Git's internal testing, and even there, there is some attempt to get rid of it.  There's only one place it appears in the Git source `Documentation` folder, and that's in the release notes for Git 2.31.0, where it is mentioned that `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` had some parsing issues before, and has fewer now, though still not "none".)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that it is not an option of fetch, but an option of git. But I didn't set GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS.(I'll add it to the text.)

Comment: Apparently something did set it. I don't know what did that, or why; you should investigate that, and have whoever did set it, stop doing that...

Comment: Aha: `git -c ...` *internally* sets this. But Git should handle its own settings: this means something is broken in your Git installation.

Comment: I'm late. I'm sorry.
The bottom line is that the installation of the git command in this environment was bad.
The git command installed with rpm worked correctly in another environment.
I built (make/makeinstall) git 2.35.2 in another environment and it worked.
After installing with rpm, it seems to be overwritten with git built by someone.

The solution was to uninstall rpm's git and then install it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, so it was a mismatch between the front end `git` command and the back end commands that actually implement things. That would explain it all, yes.